# How to get Intel i210at NIC ethernet card working on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ethernet, network-adapter, pci-express

After my Ethernet port (on asus prime z370-p) mysteriously stopped working, I bought [this PCIE ethernet card](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/product/B0CFPHV7LF).

I received [this](https://files.mazie.rocks/IMG_20240324_025825_Q5tbW.jpg). Looks different than advertised, but probably equivalent?

I am now testing this card on a completely fresh Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installation. I see a new entry appeared in `lspci`:

(note: the new entry is the `00:1c.4 PCI bridge`. I am surprised "Ethernet" is not mentioned in this listing)

```bash
maze@ubuntubread:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core 4-core Desktop Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [Coffee Lake S] (rev 08)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/555X/560/560X] (rev e5)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
```

meanwhile, `ip a` still shows only loopback device:

```
maze@ubuntubread:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Since this is not working, I assume the kernel is missing the needed drivers. I installed `igb-5.15.7.tar.gz` from [Intel's site](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/64400/intel-ethernet-controller-i210at/downloads.html) and it did not make a difference. I also installed `ice-1.13.7.tar.gz` from [e1000 on Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/) with no effect.

I am able to see both `igb` and `ice` being loaded in `dmesg`:

```
[  779.223763] dca service started, version 1.12.1
[  779.507425] igb: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  779.507474] igb: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  779.515351] igb: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Linux Driver - version 5.15.7
[  779.515353] igb: Copyright(c) 2007 - 2023 Intel Corporation.
[  795.029214] gnss: GNSS driver registered with major 511
[  796.725673] ice: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection E800 Series Linux Driver - version 1.13.7
[  796.725676] ice: Copyright (C) 2018-2023 Intel Corporation
```

But still nothing new appears in `ip a`. And `dmesg` does not show any helpful information. What can I try next?

P.S.: The story about my broken ethernet port might be relevant: after physically transporting this computer, everything still works (including PCIe graphics), *except* the motherboard ethernet port. I already tried it from live medium; and from a freshly installed OS; and I did a CMOS reset; and I closely inspected the motherboard for signs of physical damage and found nothing. So I have no idea why this happened. Or whether it could be related to the issue with the i210at.

EDIT: the output of `sudo lshw -C network` is empty.

Comment: It should, in theory work out of the box, and you shouldn't need to install the driver manually. I'd test with a livecd to confirm its a driver issue first. Also what's your netplan config look like?  I'm also fond of lshw - `sudo lshw -C network`  output might be of use

Comment: and a quick check on my router seems to indicate my I211 Nic(s) use the   igb 5.15.0-97-generic  drivers according to lshw, so in theory the drivers should be there

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks for quick response! Output of `sudo lshw -C network` is empty in my case.

Comment: That's wierd. I'd almost say your system isn't picking up the nics at all, which is *strange* and honestly quite erksome.  Intel hardware is usually painlessly supported in almost anything

Comment: another random thought. These cards in theory should do pxe boot, and as such - ought to be seen in the bios. Are they? It at least rules out complete non functionality

Comment: thanks, I will try to find it mentioned in bios. And in 2 days, I'll have a chance to try this card in a different computer too

Comment: in bios, I found `Ipv4 PXE Support` settings, but they don't appear any different whether or not the card is connected.

Comment: Tried this card on a different computer today. But was unable to get the pcie card recognized at all. I enabled "enable the PCI Slot" in bios, but surprisingly, `lspci` is still not showing a difference whether the card is inserted or not. So I don't think I can test the card here.

Comment: If it dosen't work on the different computer, maybe its dead on arrival?